# How to add feature "x-delayed-type: direct" in a queue in RabbitMQ using Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

Here it is my part of application properties:

> spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.studentInput.consumer.exchange-type=direct
>   spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.studentInput.consumer.delayed-exchange=true

But it appears that in the RabbitMQ Admin page, it does not have **x-delayed-type: direct** in the Args in feature of my queue. I am referencing to this Spring Cloud Stream documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: The `x-delayed-type` is an *exchange* feature. It fully isn't related to the queue abstraction.

Comment: See my answer - perhaps the plugin is not installed, or the exchange already exists.

Answer (score 5):

I just tested it and it worked fine.

[image]

Did you enable the plugin? If not, you should see this in the log...

> 2018-07-09 08:52:04.173 ERROR 156 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=503, reply-text=COMMAND_INVALID - unknown exchange type 'x-delayed-message', class-id=40, method-id=10)

[See the plugin documentation](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange).

Another possibility is the exchange already existed. Exchange configuration is immutable; you will see a message like this...

> 2018-07-09 09:04:43.202 ERROR 3309 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'so51244078' in vhost '/': received ''x-delayed-message'' but current is 'direct', class-id=40, method-id=10)

In this case you have to delete the exchange first.

By the way, you will need a routing key too; by default the queue will be bound with the topic exchange wildcard `#`.

Comment: I have installed the plugin in Dockerfile:

FROM rabbitmq:3.6.12-management

COPY ./rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-20171215-3.6.x.ez /plugins/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-20171215-3.6.x.ez

RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh", "rabbitmq-server"]


So I got no error like what you write. By the way, I see the x-delayed-type: direct in the exchange, not in the queue. Is that what is expected?

Comment: Yes; it's the exchange that delays the delivery.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64047133/19541281