# How to add plugin to RabbitMQ docker image?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am using `rabbitmq:3-management` from https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/ however, it is missing a plugin that I need `rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange`.

How can I enable this plugin if it is not available in the image?

Comment: Have you considered creating your own Docker image using the `rabbimq:3-management` as a base and just installing the plugin?

Comment: @UroshT. Thanks! I've never done that before, but I gave it a shot and posted an answer. It seems to work. How's my custom Docker image look? I found it strange that I had to install basics like curl and unzip.

Comment: "I found it strange that I had to install basics like curl/unzip" - they're not needed in most images, so why include them?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Well to install the RabbitMQ plugin it seems like I needed curl to download it, then I had to unzip it to get the .ez file.

Comment: @kayla but they were not needed to _run_ rabbitmq from the base image, so no wonder they aren't there.

Comment: Yes, Sergio has a point, the images are optimized so that they include only the necessary for deployment of rabbitmq. If it worked, accept your own answer so that the people having the same issue as you know how to solve it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.7-management

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y curl unzip

RUN curl https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/community-plugins/3.7.x/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-20171201-3.7.x.zip > rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-20171201-3.7.x.zip && \
unzip rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-20171201-3.7.x.zip && \
rm -f rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-20171201-3.7.x.zip && \
mv rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-20171201-3.7.x.ez plugins/

RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange
```

Comment: The Link to the (currently) latest version can be found here: https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/community-plugins/3.8.x/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-20191008-3.8.x.zip

Comment: A built a different version based on @atkayla one justo to obtain the ez file from official github repository. check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73615616/6548978

Answer (score 29):

Just updating the accepted answer. You may copy the downloaded plugin into rabbitmq image and install it.

Plugin download link: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/releases

**1. Prepare custom image:**

*Dockerfile*

```
  FROM rabbitmq:3.7.18-management
  COPY ./rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-20171201-3.7.x.ez /opt/rabbitmq/plugins/
  RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq-custom
  ports:
    - "5672:5672"
    - "15672:15672"
```

**2. Build the image**

```
docker build -t rabbitmq-custom .
```

**3. Run the docker composer:**

```
docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 29):

According to https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq it seems there is a second option not yet evoked here.
I feel accepted answer is the best solution for it allows more tweaks, but one might prefer the other method:

> ### Enabling Plugins
>
> *[Accepted answer...]*
>
> **You can also mount a file at `/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins` with contents as an erlang list of atoms ending with a period.**
>
> **Example `enabled_plugins`**
>
> ```
> [rabbitmq_federation_management,rabbitmq_management,rabbitmq_mqtt,rabbitmq_stomp].
> ```

**DISCLAIMER**: I have not tried it yet.

Comment: This really should be marked as the most effective solution.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: I think this solution would only work for the plugins included in rabbitmq by default. The plugin in this question is not one of the core plugins listed here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/plugins.html

Answer (score 12):

This is how I achieved in version 3.9

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.9-management

COPY rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Date=false update && apt-get install -y curl

RUN curl -L https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/releases/download/3.9.0/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-3.9.0.ez > $RABBITMQ_HOME/plugins/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-3.9.0.ez

RUN chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq $RABBITMQ_HOME/plugins/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-3.9.0.ez

RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange
```

Answer (score 9):

Hope this helps too:

```
rabbitmq3:
  container_name: "rabbitmq"
  image: rabbitmq:3.8-management-alpine
  environment:
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=local
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=localpwd
    - RABBITMQ_PLUGINS_DIR=/opt/rabbitmq/plugins:/usr/lib/rabbitmq/plugins
  ports:
    # AMQP protocol port
    - '5672:5672'
    # HTTP management UI
    - '15672:15672'
  volumes:
    - ./rabbit/enabled_plugins:/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins
    - ./rabbit/plugins:/usr/lib/rabbitmq/plugins
```

Add a "rabbit" folder in the same path of the docker-compose with a file called **enabled_plugins**

```
[rabbitmq_management, rabbitmq_message_deduplication].
```

then download the plugins .ez-VERSION you need in a folder plugins (within "rabbit" folder).

i.e. https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication/releases

Comment: `RABBITMQ_PLUGINS_DIR=/opt/rabbitmq/plugins:/usr/lib/rabbitmq/plugins` this trick helped me to enable plugin

Answer (score 4):

If you have already a running container than simply run

> docker exec -it NameOfContainer bash

In mycase I need to enable **rabbitmq_jms_topic_exchange**

> rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_jms_topic_exchange

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use [masstransit/rabbitmq](https://hub.docker.com/r/masstransit/rabbitmq), which is regularly updated and includes the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Just to get the plugin from the official place I propose the next Dockerfile

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.10-management-alpine

RUN apk --no-cache add curl

RUN curl -L https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/releases/download/3.10.2/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-3.10.2.ez > rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-3.10.2.ez && \
mv rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-3.10.2.ez plugins/

RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange
```

Hope to be useful!